# Why do i get a runtime error when i am trying to write a simple route in the new nextjs 13.5.4?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, runtime-error, app-router

I get this error when trying to create a simple route app/dashboard/page.tsx where by an error occurs stating the contents are not a valid react component whilst they are actually valid react component syntax

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: The default export is not a React Component in page: "/dashboard"

Call Stack
ew
/Users/mac/Documents/nextjs/rico_sub/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (13:19957)
async
/Users/mac/Documents/nextjs/rico_sub/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (13:20643)
async ew
/Users/mac/Documents/nextjs/rico_sub/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (13:20409)
async
/Users/mac/Documents/nextjs/rico_sub/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (13:20643)
async ew
/Users/mac/Documents/nextjs/rico_sub/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (13:20409)
async O
/Users/mac/Documents/nextjs/rico_sub/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js (13:25264)
```

Comment: It's better if you show your component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a function and *export* it like below :

```
export default function page() {
  return (
    //HTML code
  )
}
```